# Google Classroom API and Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-classroom

I was wondering if/when google classroom API will have javascript tutorials? I have worked on the quickstart, but having trouble finding any way to create a classroom through javascript. I have limitations in the project.

How do you create a course in the API with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the JavaScript client is basically calling the REST API.

https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/js

The REST reference is here

https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/#collection-v1courses